# adding action buttons - missing action_search and icon

Tags: android

Obviously, I am a newbie with android.  I am following the [developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html#AddActions](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html#AddActions)  tutorials but I have run into a road block with these action bar buttons & menu items.

My code compiles clean and runs on emulators but when I try to hit the menu function, on either of my MainActivity or my DisplayMessageActivity, I ONLY see the settings option not my action_search option and also missing is the icons for these options.  (the drop down only shows one option - settings).

I think that I am missing some code in my menu xml file:

```
/res/menu/main.xml:
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />


    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        yourapp:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?  I can post more code if it helps explain things that are missing.

Kind Regards,
LRW

Comment: what is your app name ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sure that your main.xml does not have any problem. Because I also suffered by this problem. It would be the problem of theme color, that means your button is right there as you defined but with an invisible color. You can change it very simply if you're using eclipse with the latest ADT version 23.0.5 (release Oct, 2014) or later.

If so, just follow steps.

1. Ctrl+N than select "Android" > "Android icon set", press "Next"
2. Choose "Action Bar and Tap icons" (2nd option)
3. Edit 'Icon Name' with the title of your action item (e.g. ic_action_search), press "Next"
4. Click "Clipboard" tab, than select the preset icon you want.
5. *Here is critical!* Lastly, you should choose the "Holo Dark" option only if your action bar's bg color seems black. If not, choose "Holo Light". Press "Finish"
6. Check whether the icon variations are correctly generated in each /res/@drawable folders.

When you create Android application project in eclipse with "Blank activity", it automatically makes its style set to [Holo Light with Dark action bar] by default.
Hope you solve that problem!

< One more tip! >
Use this code to check whether your action item responses well on click. It will show you a short toast popup with the message you set. 
Copy it and paste in your "openSearch()" function.

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Search pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't see the text of your options then you've likely inflated the incorrect menu.

In MainActivity.java be sure

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
    return true;
}
```

is passing in the correct R.menu.**Identifier** resource id. Otherwise the default menu will be used (which only contains **Settings**).